# Extend one alias in second alias

Tags: shell, alias

It is possible to do this:

```
alias tm=cd /opt/tomcat
alias tmbin=tm/bin

$ tmbin
$pwd
   /opt/tomcat/bin
```

??

I know that I can do:

```
alias tmbin=tm;cd bin
```

Comment: For this to be possible Bash would need to perform alias expansion before it performs alias expansion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a simple function:

```sh
# may contain bashisms
function tm () { cd "/opt/tomcat/$1"; }
alias tmbin='tm bin' # if that really is necessary
```

or something more complex:

```
# more configurable
function tm () {
    cd /opt/tomcat
    case "$1" in
        "foo")
            # do something funky
            ;;
        "bar")
            # do something more funky
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: You can even shorten the function to `cd "/opt/tomcat/$1"`. It does the right thing whether `$1` is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a way but the only I found was kind of complicated. For example here what I would do (though I don't recommand it for such a simple alias...)

```
alias tm="cd /opt/tomcat"
tmp=`alias tm | cut -f2 -d"="`
tmp="${tmp%\'}"
tmp="${tmp#\'}"
alias tmbin="$tmp/bin"
```

Explanation :

- First I get the raw command stored into the alias using cut and
  alias.
- Then I remove the first and last "\'" because I don't want
  a string.
- After that I got the raw alias and I can create a new
  one using that value.

Though I guess my solution isn't good at all and if anyone got a better one thanks for letting me know :)

EDIT :
A shorter solution that works the same

```
alias tm="cd /opt/tomcat"
tmp=`alias tm | cut -f2 -d"=" | cut -f2 -d"'"`
alias tmbin="$tmp/bin"
```

I have to tell you that it can be used to extend any alias. I just tested it and it works, though on longer aliases I don't know how it would react. In the case of a longer alias with a lot of "'" in it, you better use the first solution that removes the FIRST and LAST "'". It's up to you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer here in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051814/linux-possible-to-extend-and-alias)

For example to extend an alias of 'ls' by adding a '-o' you would do

```
eval "$(alias -p|grep '^alias ls='|sed "s/'$/ -o'/")"
```

Comment: why not use `alias ls` instead of `alias -p|grep '^alias ls='`?